# Edit form Selected field auto created in view mode

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am trying to make two simple display and edit forms

I have connected my mysql sources and in data i have choosen in general 2 tables.

I have created succesfully the display form by choosing one table and fields from it.

When i am trying from this specific table to select fields in the edit form, i see that the created datacards are in view mode. The program is not creating the correct fields( starvisible,errormessage,datacardvalue,datacardkey) it only creates (datacardvalue,datacardkey).

My form is edit form, with defaultmode edit.

In the same editform when i connect another table from the same db everything works fine. I have even connected a second db to check another table from there and it works fine. What should i check?

Is there anything that i should check in my DB. The differences there are that the data in the table that is not working properly are inserted with etl program but in the rest tables manually.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with PK. The tables that come from ETL did not have any PK when i have created one to the db then it worked.